# I cannot see my app when I debug my project on smartface free

Tags: smartface.io

I have installed the free version of smartface and just created a training project. When I build it my app install on virtual android device but I cannot see it. I just see the smartface adverts.

What can I do to solve this problem? Should I get it lisenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen that you mentioned is just shown at the beginning of the app for some seconds. Then you can see your application page and use it. You should reinstall it on a real android device.

Comment: Yes, it works on an android device but why it does not work on vitual devices? There are some different problems with virtual devices.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your problem exactly, can you please share a screenshot?

And maybe you can check the link below for more information about Android virtual device usage : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/virtual-devices-android/

By the way, you should create the virtual device using google api.

Comment: The problem is that when i debug my application in Smartface ide, my application is not shown in the device, the smartface images is shown in the application istead of my application.

Comment: Daha doğru anlatabilmek adına bir de Türkçe yazmak istedim. Problem şu; ben smartface in ücretsiz versiyonunu indirdim ve bir deneme projesi açıp sanal android cihaz üzerinden debug ettim ve cihaza smarface emulator adında bir uygulama yüklendi. Fakat uygulamada benim oluşturduğum ekran yerine smartface ile alakalı görseller çıkıyor. Sorun bu yani. Acaba bu problem, kullandığım versiyonun ücretsiz olmadından mı kaynaklı, lisans almam mı gerekiyor?